# Angularjs modal not working properly in spring mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, spring-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I already have these dependencies and i want to include Modal functionality.

```
var studentProfile = angular.module('studentProfile', ["xeditable"])

   // .config(function( $httpProvider){
    //  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] =    'XMLHttpRequest';
    //})    ;

studentProfile.run(function(editableOptions) {
      editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
    });

studentProfile.controller("studentProfileController", function($scope, $http, $timeout, $filter) {
//
// My studentProfileController methods
```

I tried but it did not work even the simple one. T he modal works desperately in other page but when i include it in this page it does not work.

```
<script src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/js/myModel.js"></script>
```

```
<div ng-app="mymodal" ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">
  <button ng-click="toggleModal('Success')" class="btn btn-default">Success</button>
  <button ng-click="toggleModal('Remove')" class="btn btn-default">Remove</button>
  <button ng-click="toggleModal('Deny')" class="btn btn-default">Deny</button>
  <button ng-click="toggleModal('Cancel')" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
  <modal visible="showModal">
      Any additional data / buttons
  </modal>
</div>
```

jsp page

```
<div ng-app="mymodal" ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">
  <button ng-click="toggleModal('Success')" class="btn btn-default">Success</button>
  <button ng-click="toggleModal('Remove')" class="btn btn-default">Remove</button>
  <button ng-click="toggleModal('Deny')" class="btn btn-default">Deny</button>
  <button ng-click="toggleModal('Cancel')" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
  <modal visible="showModal">
      Any additional data / buttons
  </modal>
</div>
```

Above example works fine seperately. Please show me how i can do same working with my above app.controller(studentProfile). Because when i include modal functionality my editable form stops working.

Also i have one other problem. When i put the studentProfile app in separate .js file and include it in jsp page its functions do no work. Any idea why ? The basic jsp page structure remains same like it the editable elements work but no even works when button is clicked.

Comment: AngularJS is a client side framework. Your questions and prroblem definition is so much in the context of the JSPs and server side work that it becomes difficult to understand. I would recommend not to mix the JSP and AngularJS in your application. AngularJS suits best for small/large SIngle Page Applications. However the situation I would recommend you to post snippets of the page that is already rendered on the browser. Investigate the problem there. Use Chrome browser Developer Tool.

Comment: If you want fast response/help - create a plnkr.

Comment: I just have a simple page i want to show in popup with data comong from server through ajax. And i am using angularjs for all my ajax purposes. Is it not ok to use angularjs for large websites atleast for using Ajax.

Comment: You mentioned "it worked in this page not not other page". If you have more than 1 page then how is it a Single Page App. Do you see any errors in the console ?

Comment: It is not a single page app. Just using ajax and other angularjs functions. So i should not use angularjs if i have multi page project ?